# Using an array selection to select an area in an image map

Tags: javascript, html

I am coding a game using JavaScript, in which the computer pulls a random food item from an array. The user then spells the word properly and if they are right, they are redirected to an image of a kitchen. They have to find the item that they spelled in the kitchen. Eg computer displays "papel", user inputs "apple", clicks go and sees a kitchen with various items hidden in divs which are displayed through onclicks of various areas (image mapped). However, how do I get it working so that the user only gets a "congrats" popup if they select the right item (eg. apple), as opposed to other items in the kitchen(oranges, cakes etc)? Below is the technique I am trying... (College assignment, not good at code)

```js
function appleans() {

    if (document.getElementById("apple").className == words[count].correct) {
        alert("Good job!");
        document.getElementById("fruitbowl").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("landingpage").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        alert("Try Again!");
    }

}
```

```html
<div id="fruitbowl">

    <img src="Imagesbg/bowl.png" class="bowl" alt="" usemap="#fruitbowl" />

    <map name="fruitbowl" id="fruitbowl">

        <area alt="apple" title="" href="" onClick="appleans(); return false;" shape="poly" coords="325,211,287,246,265,302,263,345,274,388,78,335,57,246,80,182,145,149,156,114,288,159" />

        <area alt="orange" title="" href="" onClick="orangeans(); return false;" shape="poly" coords="284,389,269,342,281,272,309,235,336,204,421,165,515,186,565,222,597,273,608,336,601,377,460,391" />

        <area alt="banana" title="" href="" shape="poly" onClick="bananaans(); return false;" coords="559,207,594,151,619,123,615,66,652,38,681,95,713,120,744,167,748,219,746,267,731,310,722,343,609,373,616,319,600,251" />
    </map>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear how your "words" array is set up, and I don't see any class associated with the map area.  I think you are simply trying to something like this:

First add the **id** attribute and change the function call to **chooseFruit** to the areas in the map as such:

```
<area alt="apple" id="apple" title="" href="" onClick="chooseFruit('apple'); return false;" shape="poly" coords="325,211,287,246,265,302,263,345,274,388,78,335,57,246,80,182,145,149,156,114,288,159" />
```

Make a similar change to the other fruit areas in the map - i.e. added **id** and changed function call to **chooseFruit**

**Edit**: made the function more generic so it can be reused for all the fruits.

Then in your javascript:

```
...

  var correctWord = words[count];

  function chooseFruit(fruit) {

    if (fruit == correctWord)  {
         alert("Good job!");
         document.getElementById("fruitbowl").style.display = "none"; 
         document.getElementById("landingpage").style.display = "block"; 
     } else {
        alert("Try Again!");
     }  

  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked, thank you so much! One more question- There are other ares of the "kitchen" that can be selected to look for certain items (ie. fridge, cupboards etc). For this could I just treat the mapping the same as above, but with a different function for each area (ie. fridge etc)?

Comment: You're quite welcome :-) If those other **items** are also in the `words[...]` array and in the same map, then you can use this same function. You might then want to make the function slighty more abstract for the sake of readability. For example: `function chooseItem(item) { if (item == correctWord) ...`. Also you'd have to change the areas in the map to `onClick="chooseItem(...); ...` accordingly.